# File a patent disclosure after paper acceptance

Tags: publications, arxiv, patents

We were trying to file a patent, but unfortunately delayed the submission of the disclosure. Now the paper is accepted by the conference, not yet published. However, we uploaded the paper in advanced to arxiv.org.

Is there any problems to file our disclosure now? We are in an urgent situation and need to file the patent on behalf of our company.

I'm in the US.

Comment: Retain a patent lawyer

Comment: This depends on the country.  In some countries, you were out of luck as soon as your paper appeared on the arXiv; in others, you have a grace period to fill the patent application after public disclosure.  Either way, Fábio Dias is right that you need to talk to a lawyer.  Presumably you are already working with one on the patent application; if not, then you really need to catch up on this.  (Ideally, you should already have been talking with a lawyer when you started writing the paper, not just after it has appeared on the arXiv.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question, rather than a question about academia.

Comment: Of further interest also: "First-to-file" principle (US). For this question, as said earlier, a patent lawyer is a good investment. View any concrete advice from this site on such an issue with suspicion.

Comment: @FábioDias that's my question. Can lawyer do something about it? Or they can just answer the question? We already have a lawyer but didn't told her about the arxiv thing.

Comment: @TinaJ: Not telling her about the arXiv submission is a big deal, since legal advice is useless if you don't keep your lawyer well informed.  You should send her an e-mail immediately.  Hopefully it won't be a problem, but only your lawyer understands the details of your situation well enough to say for sure (and that's only if you tell her everything relevant!).